# glassfish server JDK/JRE issue

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

I am trying to setup grassfish4 server in my eclipse Juno. I have both JDK1.8.0-05 and jre8 installed. When I am creating the new server, I get this for selecting JDK1.8.0-0
"This server runtime requires JRE 1.7 or higher.".

and when I select jre, I get this "Glassfish server runtime requires full JDK instead of JRE".

In the preference-java-Installed JREs tab, I have my JDK checked. and pointing to the location C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_05 and my jre unchecked pointing to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre8.

What settings I need to do to fix this problem? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GlassFish 4 does not support Java 8 yet. There is a 4.0.1 release planned for later this year that will fix this.